# eclipse (php) works slow and then crashes while coding

Tags: php, windows, eclipse, windows-8, wamp

I'm a PHP web developer 
my eclipse strangely works really slow and then crashes.
i use windows 8 64bit
lenovo laptop G500 i7 8G 
i didnt have this problem before it worked properly

i tried reinstalling wamp because maybe something went wrong with my workspace folder. 
and reinstalled java 
when i open the task manager, it shows me that java crashed.

what can the problem be? 
that is the error i get after the eclipse crashes: (cant upload photo to this site because i dont have enough points..)
http://i44.tinypic.com/r8azpx.png

Comment: I disagree with close votes for "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow **unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming**." I don't use it personally, but I hear people use Eclipse as a tool primarily for programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same thing happened to me with Eclipse Kepler and the latest PHP CodeSniffer. Surprisingly, it happens on a Win7 64bit machine but *not* on a Windows XP SP3 machine with, as far as I can tell, the same software configuration (compatible with the different architecture).

After browsing the Eclipse forum I tried increasing Eclipse's maximum heap space from 256 (I see you have 384) to 512 Mb on the 64bit machine. This somehow fixed things, even if I could not see, and still *can't* see, how CodeSniffer or any other part of PDT could ever eat up 256 Mb (XP is satisfied with 256. Go figure).

I'm blaming CodeSniffer because things started going awry after updating *that*. But as I said, nothing seems detectably wrong with CS. Crashes happened (not too predictably) a couple seconds after saving some PHP files, without any definite link to file size, number of lines, functions, or anything. It is fully possible that the problem was elsewhere.

Anyway, for what is worth, you can try too. Find the [`eclipse.ini` file](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) and raise the `Xmx` parameter from 384 to 512 M.

## Log

The last activity in the log is indeed a memory error:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2013-12-11 22:19:53.504
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.EcoreFactoryImpl.createEAttribute(EcoreFactoryImpl.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.EPackageImpl.createEAttribute(EPackageImpl.java:785)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.EcorePackageImpl.createPackageContents(EcorePackageImpl.java:2286)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.EcorePackageImpl.init(EcorePackageImpl.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EcorePackage.<clinit>(EcorePackage.java:73)
```

So, either you need **still more memory**, or there's some kind of leaky loop that will exhaust *any* quantity of memory (it will just take longer to do so). The latter case would point to a bug in Eclipse or one of its components, **but** it could also be that your workspace is corrupt, since I also read

```
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.
```

So, another thing to attempt is to start eclipse from the command line with:

```
eclipse -clean -cleanPersistedState
```

and see whether this fixes the problem.

Comment: I edited it to 512 
and surprisingly it didnt crash so fast
but it still crashed and gave me an error of "an error has occured. see the log file c:\wamp\www\.metadata\.log "

and i cant even find the file in this folder :X

Comment: But you now have an error log! What does it say?

Comment: cant copy-paste it because its too long..
there it is
http://musti.co.il/media/thelog.txt